# How to measure the range of a horizontal projectile?

Tags: experimental-physics, kinematics, projectile, home-experiment

For an experiment, I'm launching a projectile horizontally to determine the relationship between height and range. Pretty basic stuff. But I'm having trouble coming up with an effective way to measure the range.

I was using carbon paper to leave marks on plain paper which I can then measure, but the weight of the projectile I'm using just doesn't leave a decent enough mark to be sure that it actually landed there. I'm after a way of doing this that is more reliable.

For scale, the heights are about from 40cm to 70cm, and the range is only between 1 and 2 meters.

Answer (score 1):

There are so many ways you can do that:

- put some sand on the floor (Like Olympics!)
- Lay some papers on the ground, and put your thrown object in the ink. then when it lands it will make a mark (actually this method were used my famous physicist Galileo Galilei )
- pour down some Bean or nuts on the ground, then when object hit them it will make a mark (this way is easiest I think)
- put some meters on the ground and use your eye to detect where was the closest landing mark
- use videos and playbacks afterward (this is the actual way that physicist do their experiment about movement)

and so many other methods...

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a few equidistant lines on the paper that is on the floor and make a video of the falling projectile.